# Empty page.tpl.php renders data too

Tags: 7, theming

I created my own theme in Drupal 7. It is not sub-theme. Simple I created a folder at sites/all/themes/my_foundation, a template.info as usual, then an empty page.tpl.php.

I expected that a blank white page is obtained after enabling the new theme and visiting the home page. However, I have got a page with some contents as screenshot:
[image]

I need to know how it was occurred and how could I get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior if page.tpl is missing:

Since your theme does not print anything in page, the Core system module (the one that defines page.tpl.php etc) takes over and drupal uses system's page.tpl.

I suppose that if page.tpl is **empty** the default page array is rendered with any region that exists in your theme's.info and has content.If regions exist, Drupal will try to render them even without template.

Comment: Yes it is, it was an empty file, it was just file system file in the theme folder named page.tpl.php with `<?php ?>` as content only. doing some printing solves the issue with copying html.tpl.php to the theme too. I think there is a bug in clear cache of my testing Drupal version that I have.

Comment: same with a blank html.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Use empty_front_page module.

By Install and active this module front pagecin drupal is clear.